# Starting Vim at a certain position (line and column) of a file

Tags: vim

To start at a specific line I would use:

```
$ vim FILE +LINE
```

But what parameter needs to be passed to vim to position the cursor in a certain column of this line?

Comment: Isn't it easy enough to just type the column number and then `l` after the file is opened?

Comment: No, since I don't know the exact column. Vim should be started by a script.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

One way to do that would be:

```
vim "+call cursor(<LINE>, <COLUMN>)"
```

For completeness this is another way:

```
vim "+normal <LINE>G<COLUMN>|"
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I asked this same question on #vim on Libera and got the answer from markzen. This oneliner will do the trick.

```
vim foo +45 +'norm$' +'star!'
```