# How to pass line/col number to gvim from grepwin?

Tags: windows, vim, grep

I can configure grepwin to launch an external text editor using this:

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe -n%line% %path%
```

What the above does is:

1. Open Notepad++
2. Open the text file from %path%
3. Goto %line% where the grep match occurs.

Can I do something similar with gvim?

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly for positioning cursor to specific line & column. Credit goes to related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313469/234994

`C:\path\to\gvim.exe %path% "+normal %line%G%column%|"`

Comment: Well in that case your question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't launch (g)vim with proper column location easily. The way to set your line is:

```
C:\path\to\gvim.exe %path% +%line%
```

At least you can try with the -c option, like

```
C:\path\to\gvim.exe %path% -c %line% -c "normal %COLUMN%l"
```

(You didn't specify how grepwin specifies the column, so I had used `%COLUMN%`.

Comment: Line method works but I'm trying the column -c switch but doesn't give me the correct results. I'm manually testing: `gvim.exe %path% -c 3 -c "normal 3"` and it goes to Line 6, Col 1. I'm expecting Line 3, Col 3

Comment: Actually there is an extra '`l`' in my example right after the `%COLUMN%`...

Comment: ok, I'm testing `gvim.exe %path% -c 3 -c "normal 31"` and it gives weird results. The column seems correct and is 4 but everytime I test it, it adds 3 lines. So 1st time I see (Lin3,Col4) quit/open (Lin6,Col4) quit/open (Lin9,Col4) quit/open (Lin12/Col4)

Comment: I made sure to quit all instances of gvim, and reran `gvim.exe %path% -c 3 -c "normal 31"` but the line number seems to be sticky, it always remembers and adds 3 lines... is there some way to reset to forget last line position?

Comment: Because you might have some `.viminfo` file/settings which are able to reopen the file at the exact same location. Just use google for it. And you might accept/upvote the answer which helps you the most...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this command:

```
C:\path\to\gvim.exe %path% +%line%
```